# NetBeans stdout and stderr on Linux

Tags: linux, netbeans, command-line, standard-error

How can I get the stdout and stderr from NetBeans 7.4 on Linux? If I run NetBeans from the command-line (Ubuntu 14), NetBeans appears to redirect everything to /dev/null, according to what I'm seeing in the bin/netbeans script. I would like to see stdout and stderr sent to my terminal. I've even tried modifying the bin/netbeans script to pipe the output to files, but it's not giving me all of the stdout and stderr (I'm not a bash scripting expert, though). The meager help available with "netbeans --help" doesn't provide any clues to stdout/stderr, and I've failed to turn anything up on Google.

I need stdout and stderr because the NetBeans IDE itself is throwing an exception when switching to the "Design" view of a Swing component, and it's not giving me the full stacktrace I need to track down the problem (there's some static init code in one class that is likely causing the issue, but it works great at runtime and I see no issues with the code). If I run the netbeans.exe in Windows, I get all of the stderr and stdout in my cmd.exe window just fine, but I need to do this in Ubuntu 14. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBeans uses Java logging for all of its error messages. These messages are displayed in the Output window within NetBeans and saved to a log file. The log file is located at  **$HOME/.netbeans/7.4/messages.log**.

In my experience, the log file contains more information than is displayed in the NetBeans Output window.

Comment: This is so, the path may have moved though.  I'm looking at Netbeans 9.00, the path is `--userdir` then: `./var/log/messages.log`